# How do I allow outgoing connections only for a particular user in UFW?

Tags: flask, urllib2, mod-wsgi

I have a hosting server where I have apache webserver installed along with mod_wsgi. My server runs on python flask. Some of the libraries I am using use urllib2 and when I deny all the outgoing connections, urrlib2 also stops working.

Can someone either tell me which port does urllib2 use or how can I allow outgoing connections for any process started by a particular user?

Here is my firewall rules so far:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```